# To ]8;;https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/new\submit an issue]8;;\ include the stack trace

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

## Issue summary

I am getting this error whenever I try to start the development server

### Expected behavior

Shopify node serve should run the development server

### Actual behavior

What actually happens?

```text
C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\myfirsttest>shopify node serve
X An unexpected error occured.
        To ]8;;https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/new\submit an issue]8;;\ include the stack trace.

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/process_supervision.rb:40:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000" (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/process_supervision.rb:40:in `for_ident'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/process_supervision.rb:127:in `running?'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/process_supervision.rb:62:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/tunnel.rb:189:in `start_ngrok'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/tunnel.rb:68:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/project_types/node/commands/serve.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/sub_command.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/command.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/stdout_router.rb:169:in `with_id'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:36:in `block in with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:176:in `log_output_to'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:35:in `with_logging'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:16:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:44:in `block in with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:51:in `twrap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:43:in `with_traps'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/executor.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/entry_point.rb:24:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/monorail.rb:30:in `log'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/lib/shopify_cli/core/entry_point.rb:23:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/bin/shopify:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in `handle_abort'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/bin/shopify:36:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.6.6/bin/shopify:47:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/shopify:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/shopify:23:in `<main>'
```